# Wait Handles and Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, waithandle

I am currently working on a proof of concept application using the Xamarin free trial, and I have hit a rather interesting little problem... Here is the code I am using within a Portable Class Library:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace poc
{
    public class CurrentWeatherInformation
    {

        public string WeatherText { get; set; }

        public CurrentWeatherInformation (string cityName)
        {
            // api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Leeds
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}", cityName));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            object state = request;

            var ar = request.BeginGetResponse (WeatherCallbackMethod, state);
            var waitHandle = ar.AsyncWaitHandle as System.Threading.ManualResetEvent;

            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        public void WeatherCallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            object state = ar.AsyncState;
            var request = state as HttpWebRequest;
            var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
            var data = new System.IO.StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ()).ReadToEnd ();
            this.WeatherText = data;
        }

    }
}
```

Essentially, I just want to call against a webservice and get a response, but I note with Xamarin that I am unable to do this using the good old `GetResponse()` method, and have to use `BeginGetResponse()` and `EndGetResponse()` instead, with the old `IAsyncResult` pattern. Shizzle.

Anyway, my problem is that the code following my waiting on the `waitHandle` is executing BEFORE the code in the callback, and I don't see why. This is precisely what we have the wait handle for!

Can anyone spot what I am sure will prove to be a simple mistake by a simpleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Phone you are forced to use the async API. When you try to wait for a result of an async method synchronously on main thread you can end up in an infinite loop. 
Use `async` and `await` when you do expensive things. It's the common pattern for doing asynchronous work.

Take a look at some tutorials:

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/10/01/asynchronous-operations-with-xamarin.aspx

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/

[How to implement Android callbacks in C# using async/await with Xamarin or Dot42?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779793/how-to-implement-android-callbacks-in-c-sharp-using-async-await-with-xamarin-or)

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/HttpClient/HttpClientDemo/GeoNamesWebService.cs

Comment: The problem is that (and I've amended my question accordingly) the code I have shown you is in a portable class library, which means that GetResponseAsync etc isn't available. Literally the only option I have is BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse...

Comment: No, you have more options. You can use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`with `async`/`await`. That's the common way in Xamarin to comsume webservices as shown in the tutorials.

Comment: Looks like we can't use System.Net.Http in Xamarin because it's Nuget implementation isn't far enough along (< 3). 

Tried switching to Visual Studio and now the project doesn't compile. I am starting to get annoyed with this lol...

Comment: What do you mean with `System.Net.Http` "isn't far enough along"? It's stable and many people use it in their productive apps.

Comment: When I try to get the nuget package I am getting a warning that Xamarin's nuget client, being 2.8.3 I think, is not high enough to bring down the package. It claims to need 3 +. Despite that though, it seems that ir has brought down the package...

Comment: I'm sorry. Use `Microsoft.Net.Http` instead. The difference is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053243/system-net-http-vs-microsoft-net-http